# inline element with inside tailing space will remove space between siblings?

Tags: html, css

```css
span {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>without tailing space in first span</p>
<span>aaa</span>
<span>bbb</span>
</div>

<div>
<p>with tailing space in first span</p>
<span>aaa </span>   
<span>bbb</span>
</div>
```

in the code snippet above, we can see that if there is a blank space after "aaa", it will remove the space between two spans.

[image]

I'm confused, is this behavior part of the browser render specification?

Comment: browsers tend to only show one whitespace character between inline elements (unless you force more with non breaking space characters) so you can indent your code to make it look neat.  I would say this is expected behaviour as in your first example, the first whitespace is outside the span and in the second it is in (the remaining after the first are removed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's the intended result. To understand this you need to refer to the [white space algorithm](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#white-space-prop)

> 2. any space (U+0020) following another space (U+0020) — even a space before the inline, if that space also has 'white-space' set to 'normal', 'nowrap' or 'pre-line' — is removed.

So basically when you have N spaces we keep only the first one and in the second case, the first space is inside the `span` while in the first case, it's outside of it.

More examples:

```css
span {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
<span>aaa</span><span>    bbb</span>
</div>
<div>
<span>aaa </span><span>    bbb</span>
</div>
```

Comment: It's pointing out that this only applies to `inline` content, if those spans were `inline-block`, the whitespace would be rendered differently.

Comment: @DBS yes, the algorithm start with *each inline element*